# Scale both images in div to fit viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, image-scaling

I want that both images would scale together and will fit to viewport.

I was trying to make some max-width parameters, but as the images has different width (same height) they are scaling differently.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://cdn.img42.com/3bb8d43ca012533b5ceb2ac691b7c953.png">
    <img src="https://cdn.img42.com/9bc6aad61f6967d1ec85a15dbfc462e0.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background:orange;
}

.images {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.images img {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8fc7hnff/5/

It should be really really easy, but i can't find the right solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `block-inline` should be `inline-block`

Comment: @haim770 updated, any hints to solve it?

Comment: you must need to add one another class with 100% width and apply this class on ist image that have  smaller width. like: .extra{width: 100%}

Comment: @devpro i have tried to add % width, but it doesn't scale both images together as their width is different.

Comment: @MIC: try this <img style="width:100%;" src="https://cdn.img42.com/3bb8d43ca012533b5ceb2ac691b7c953.png"> for First image and check.... i told you its not a good suggestion.

Comment: @devpro but i need them BOTH to resize :) that's the problem :)

Comment: @MIC: than apply width:100 on both images.

Comment: @devpro :) thats the problem in my question, that they DON'T scale together :) i need that their height would be the same :) (as i wrote above - "I was trying to make some max-width parameters, but as the images has different width (same height) they are scaling differently.")

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to fit images to a div and those images are of different aspect rations from the div, then the only option left is to stretch the image until the image fits the div size.

This is not good. Most likely the image is going to look really bad. If this is for a slider or an image representational or symbolic purpose, you would rather use images that actually fit the div or edit the image in such a way that it is stretched to the div. This is the correct way of doing it.

However there are ways to make sure the aspect ratio is maintained. ut doing this makes the div's are of different sizes.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.container').find('img').each(function() {
        var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
        $(this).addClass(imgClass);
    })
})
```

```css
.container {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    background: #444;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container img.wide {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.container img.tall {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img src="https://cdn.img42.com/3bb8d43ca012533b5ceb2ac691b7c953.png" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
 <img src="https://cdn.img42.com/9bc6aad61f6967d1ec85a15dbfc462e0.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: this is nice explanation.

Comment: Hm, but i need to have them side by side, so this is not what I want to achieve :(

Comment: exactly what i said mate, only option u have is to stretch the picture. that will ruin the image. Do you not mind stretching the picture?

Comment: no, stretching the picture is not good :) hm strange that where is no other option here ;( anyway, thank you for your time and hints.